# Error when creating new conda env

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, numba

I'm getting this when creating a new environment (under Ubuntu):

```
conda create -n myenv numba
```

> Error: Could not open
>   u'/myhome/.conda/envs/.pkgs/libgfortran-1.0-0.tar.bz2.part' for
>   writing (seek).

Comment: Hi @bob, have you tried this https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/416 or this https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/Jv0z9LlJt9A ?

Comment: Have you tried biopython instead:`conda create --name myenv biopython`